# Compiled program won't System.out

Tags: java, output, compiled

I created a runnable .jar, but it doesn't seem to start. I use System.out.println(), but there is 0 output. Do I have to do something else in order to output something, or can you only output something in the console when testing in Eclipse, and not when you have compiled the program?

I run my .jar by double-clicking, guess that's the way to do it...

Nevermind me, I just googled it and it should be done by using the command line! So, in advance, Google before asking... Sorry!

EDIT: I tried running `java -jar [FILENAME]` (with correct filepath), but it says that 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, while I have java installed. I found on Google that you had to edit the PATH, did that and it still didn't work... Can someone help me?

Comment: Use Logger instead of System.out.print.

Comment: Would be a great help if you told us how exactly run your jar.

Answer (score 0):

System.out works fine in the regulat terminal, not just Eclipse.

You must have something else wrong. I suggest you add `System.out.println("Starting my program");` as the first line in your `main()` method.

If you do not get this as output, then it is certain that you are not in fact running **your** program, but perhaps something else.

With the information you have given it is not possible to say what that other things could be, or what you have wrong.

Adding `-verbose:class` when you run your jar may help you figure some things out, but, it may also just make things more complicated too.

Comment: I rightclick on my project package explorer in eclipse, then export to runnable .jar file. Is that right? Or do I have to export something else?

Comment: What was the main class (launch configuration) you specified in eclipse when you did the export?

Comment: It was the one with the main function, see edit.